# Delete a shortcut using "erase" or "del" commands in cmd.exe

Tags: cmd, directory, shortcut, delete-file, erase

When I try to delete folder shortcuts from command prompt it deletes the target folder contents.
Can anyone help me to find another way to just delete shortcut?

Comment: This was answered on [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/questions/167076/how-can-i-delete-a-symbolic-link). And actually belongs there anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [Christian K.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/21567/christian-k) I found the answer:
First I created a .lnk file (shortcut) with mklink but when I used del or erase to delete shortcut target file contents deleted. So now we can use rmdir to remove just shortcut.